# My CSS/SCSS code is not being shown in specific views

Tags: css, sass

This is my first time using SCSS and I've got a major question. I started to clean my code and organize them to how it's shown in my project. For example, login info would be in application.css.scss while logout header or even a user profile would be placed in user.css.scss. Before I started organizing everything, I had no issue, but now my comment.css.scss file won't work for my rendered comment file.

Might be confusing so here is an easier example:

- User profile has commenting option. Comment.css.scss is working and look clean
- Community show page also has commenting option. Comment.css.scss isn't working and within inspect it shows all ID/Classes to be empty.

**Application.css.scss**

```
 *= communities.css
 *= users.css
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/

@import 'comments';
```

I made my comment.css.scss into a partial by making it into _comment.css.scss as I read online so I can import the files into other files.

**Communities.css.scss**

```
@import 'comments';
```

Users.css.scss file also has @import 'comments'; on top. I would like to know if anyone can explain to me why comments formating isn't working when I access the community page. Thank you for all those who help me get a better understanding to SCSS and importing different scss files.

For more information please ask, I'll try my best to answer all questions.

Comment: why you put .css.scss why not put .scss ?

Comment: @JamesPratt-Delzenne It's my first time using SCSS and I've seen some example online where people kept the file as CSS.SCSS. I just changed it but does it make a big difference between the two extensions?

Comment: normaly no, my scss files names are _name.scss and when i'm importing them it's @import 'name'; the underscore.name is conventionnal and the parser recognise it. I just didn't know that you can use .css.scss.

for the problem you should look if it realy compiled to css. and look in your css the lines that you wrote in your scss.

Comment: I think in your case it should be " @import 'comment.css'; " if your partial file is _comment.css.scss, because the .css is counted as part of the file name instead of the file extension. And check if you have typo - should it be "comments" or "comment"?